# Javascript innerHTML not working and placing in the wrong spot

Tags: javascript, html

I have this div inside a table.

```
<table>
<tr>...</tr>
<div class="injector" id="inject1"></div>
<tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

Using javascript I'm tring to inject some other html inside "inject1". My JS is:

```
document.getElementById("inject1").innerHTML+="<tr><td><h3 class='description'>Runway visual range:</h3></td></tr><tr><td><h4 class='description'>Runway number:</h4></td><td><input type='text' class='dataField' id='runwayNumber' disabled></input></td></tr><tr><td><h4 class='description'>Runway visibility:</h4></td><td><input type='text' class='dataField' id='runwayVisibility' disabled></input></td></tr>";
```

but for some reason, instead of putting the new table rows in the midddle of the table (where the div is), it puts the new lines on top of the table, and without the proper alignment. If i manually paste the same exact code (the one inside the quotation marks), it works just fine.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing "*where the div is*" in the context of the parent HTML table of which you speak.

Comment: `TR` directly in `DIV` is invalid HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

A DIV is not a valid child of a table so the browser renders the code differently to make it valid. You should be using a tbody element

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="injector" id="inject1"></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```